# Control bones keep sliding off mesh when posing

Tags: rigging, bones, pose-mode

I've been following a rigging tutorial on youtube and noticed something odd on my end. [In the tutorial video](https://youtu.be/upyDWysrhqw?t=168) (link includes relevant timestamp), the bones that control lips appear "glued" to the exact same spot on the lips no matter how they're moved in pose mode.

When I attempt to create the same however, the bone always slides off the further from the rest pose it gets. Like it's influence isn't strong enough. I've recorded [a short video](https://youtu.be/kz8byFYBNCk) demonstrating the issue.

Does anyone know what might be causing this and how to avoid it? The only thing I thought might be a problem is perhaps some scaling issues with the rigged object, but it still happens to me even in fresh project where I haven't scaled anything.

Thank you

Comment: The another bone also has infuence on that part.

Comment: yes as FFeller says one or several bones have influence on that part while you'd like only the top bone to have influence, so use the Weight Paint mode to correct that, or maybe remove this part from all the other vertex groups in the Vertex Groups list